# Parse irc/twitch chat for username and message name

Tags: c#, irc

I want to write a program that can display and write messages into the twitch chat, currently I don't plan on building a bot.

I am receiving the messages in this format `:tmi.twitch.tv 001 <nick>:<message>`.

Currently my biggest problem is to extract the components of this message and store them to a class that I can later expand.
Does somebody know a way to do this in a good readable manner? 
You don't need to write code, I am interested in some solution ideas.

Comment: Go Google `string.Split` and then perhaps run through some basic C# tutorials. :)

Comment: As @DavidG says, it's easy in C#, but if you don't know much about C# I would greatly recommend running through some tutorials or courses.

Comment: Seems trivial enough to implement your own parser for (which isn't a bad skill to cultivate).

Comment: @DavidG I am going to try that thank you!